# Transform entity / normalized response

Tags: redux, reselect, normalizr

I wonder where is a good place to transform a response entity(ies) before it is set in my Redux state.

**Example**

- I have a `chat_message` entity
- It has a `read` boolean property sent by the server
- I need to compute a new `unread` boolean property = `!message.read && message.user_id !== currentUser.id`

**Questions**

1. Do I compute this new attribute in a `getChatMessages` selector (`reselect`)?
2. Do I compute this new attribute before I set the normalized response in my state? – Hence my question "Transform"
3. Do I just calculate it in my `Component`, but this (simple) logic is not shared and duplicated all over the place...
4. Do I send the `unread` attribute from the server...

**Notes**

- `unread` attribute example is a simplified example.
- I don't like solution 1., cause you need to share this logic between selectors anyway. So you might have a `isMessageUnread` helper function shared by `getLastChatMessage`, `getChatMessages` selectors. I also don't like selectors doing too much logic.
- I would lean towards solution 2. New `unread` attribute is computed only when receiving response.
- Solution 3. is my current lazy solution (with experiments here and there but nothing conclusive really)
- I don't like solution 4., these attributes are more UI-related than backend-related.
- If using solution 2., I feel like `reducers` is not a good place to do this tranformations. Might be easy for simple entities, but what about "heavy" transformation (iterating over collections, checking relationships, etc) ? I would prefer to put that new logic outside of: selectors, reducers, and entities. Kinda like a normalizr "plugin" / interceptor / transformer / post-processor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalizr provides the [`processStrategy` option](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#entitykey-definition---options--):

> Strategy to use when pre-processing the entity. Use this method to add
>   extra data, defaults, and/or completely change the entity before
>   normalization is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how the attribute will be used :

- Is the `unread` attribute specific to one single component for its render purpose and not used anywhere else. Eg : A notification dot. If yes, then you can use solution 3, as you can localise the usage within the component.
- If the `unread` attribute, needs to be shared across components / middlewares, placing the logic in the selector / reducer is the way to go. But if you are placing in the reducer, ask whether `unread` is required by all components subscribing to `chatBox` entity. If not then it is better to place it in a selector, that can be invoked only by those components / middlewares that need it. There is a tradeoff of an extra runtime computation but it provides proper separation of concern as this will eventually benifit if there are more such derived attributes in the future.

Comment: Fair point about better separation of concern in selectors. `unread` might not be needed by all components needing `chat_message` entity(ies). Although I still think solution 2. keeps things lean (less code – less specific selectors for everything, set `unread` once, use it everywhere (or not))

Comment: Yes. If its just a couple of such derived attributes, it makes sense. But as the application grows, if there are more such attributes for different components, storing them in state will be inefficient. Take the call based on what the situation calls for. You can go with the current approach and always refractor later.